# TSQL Get max value and use that insert rows into another table that has no identify

Tags: t-sql, insert, max

I need to insert new records into another table.  The original table does NOT have an identity column.  I wrote the below query to do the insert, but it's inserting 0 records.  I'm trying to avoid using a cursor.

```
Powerpath.dbo.med_specialty  MAX(id) = 57
Connect_Onprem.dbo.med_specialty MAX(id) = 55
```

I would expect to see 2 rows inserted into Connect_Onprem.dbo.med_specialty.

I'm incrementing the ID + 1 to not get a primary key violation.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
INSERT INTO Connect_Onprem.dbo.med_specialty(id, code, name, active)
        SELECT 
        ms.id,
        ms.code,
        ms.name,
        ms.active
        FROM Powerpath_Dev.dbo.med_specialty ms  
        JOIN Connect_Onprem.dbo.med_specialty cms  ON ms.id = cms.id
        WHERE ms.active = 'Y'
        and ms.id = (SELECT MAX(id)+1 from 
               Connect_Onprem.dbo.med_specialty ms1 where ms1.id = ms.id)
```

Comment: nolock is a really bad idea for this

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I'll get rid of those.  stupid mistake.. Long day!

Comment: It's a bad idea to try to generate the primary key like this (you should use an `identity` field instead). However, assuming you want to do this, you can't have that in the `where` clause: By definition, no rows will match `max(id)+1` since the biggest one is `max(id)`. You need to move that into your `select` (and probably add some `rownumber` logic too).

Comment: What do you ***believe*** the last line of your query is doing? (This question would be vastly improved with a [mre], as suggested here; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952))

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said somewhat. You are using two different tables and I don't know how the `max(id)` in one relates to the other, but it still seems likely that the problem is as I implied.

Comment: The Powerpath_dev.dbo_med_specialty is the originating table.  the other table is a copy of this and basically, this is an ETL setup to move new records over to the staging table.  This is a vendor database so I have no control over the originating table and it's lack of identify column (which I agree is terrible).    What I thought I was gaining from the subquery is being able to increment the ID for each time it inserts to avoid primary key violation for trying to insert the same ID over and over.

Comment: @EdmCoff could you share a short example of what you are referring to.

Comment: If you are just moving records, can you not just use the ids from the originating table? That would be like in FAB's answer. I can give you an example of incrementing the id in the `select`, but if you are truly just moving records, I don't understand your `join` using `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could just insert (or merge) the values where not exists already?

```sql
INSERT INTO Connect_Onprem.dbo.med_specialty(id, code, name, active)
SELECT 
    ms.id,
    ms.code,
    ms.name,
    ms.active
FROM
    Powerpath_Dev.dbo.med_specialty SRC  
    LEFT JOIN Connect_Onprem.dbo.med_specialty TGT  ON TGT.id = SRC.id AND SRC.active = 'Y'
WHERE
    TGT.id IS NULL
```

Comment: You're awesome!  That works even better than what I was wanting to do!  Thank you all so much for sharing your comments.